# How to use sendEnrollmentEmail in Meteor

Tags: meteor

The doc about `sendEnrollmentEmail` is too short, I can not understand how it works.

My code can not create a new user. It only prints the email content in the console and the link in the email `http://localhost:3000/#/enroll-account/D4SGgWerKrdNfYrJW` only redirects to `localhost:3000/` and I can not find the token that should be pass to `Accounts.resetPassword` as the doc said.

```
Meteor.methods({
  createNewUser: function (username, email) {
    Meteor.call("validateUsername", username);
    Meteor.call("validateEmail", email);
    var userId = Accounts.createUser({username: username, email: email});
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
  }
});
```

Is there any example about `sendEnrollmentEmail`? thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You did everything correct.. I tried to get it working and it works for me fine. (Which version of meteor are you using?)

```js
if (Meteor.isServer) {    
  Meteor.methods({
  createNewUser: function (username, email) {
    // i recommend to create user with initial password otherwise it will be empty string
    var userId = Accounts.createUser({username: username, email: email, password: 'initialPassword'});
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
  }
  });
}
```

After that I got "email" in console, click on the link open my browser where popup "window" for password change

Comment: thanks! I found `D4SGgWerKrdNfYrJW` in the url is the "token" and I add a router to get it from the url. And with the env variable ROOT_URL and MAIL_URL I finally got the email with the correct content

Comment: @QingYun Hi! Do you have have a sample?